# maximal cliques on wiki

Tags: clique, clique-problem

Maximal cliques in the graph model shown on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)#/media/File:VR_complex.svg) 
has included cliques of size 3 and 4 only. But I think cliques of size 2 (which are connecting the 3,4 size cliques) should also be included in maximal cliques according to definition mentioned. Can anybody correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: The article never claims anything about which 2-vertex cliques are or aren't maximal.

Comment: In my opinion if there are 2 - vertex maximal cliques it should have been mentioned. Anyways , can you confirm whatever I am thinking is correct , just for my understanding.

Comment: There are definitely maximal cliques of size 2 in that graph.

Comment: @user2357112 , if you can write that as an answer, i will mark that as correct. If you can edit on wiki that will be great.  thanks